# Can anyone please check if I am doing this hashing correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, fnv

I am trying to do an implementation of [Fowler–Noll–Vo hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function)

The Pseudocode looks like this

```
  hash = FNV_offset_basis
   for each byte_of_data to be hashed
        hash = hash × FNV_prime
        hash = hash XOR byte_of_data
   return hash
```

This is my code for that

```
uint8_t            byte_of_data;
uint16_t          hash;
uint16_t          FNV_offset_basis;
uint16_t          FNV_prime;
void computeHash(std::string p)
{
    FNV_offset_basis =  0xcbf29ce484222325;
    FNV_prime        =  0x100000001b3;

    hash = FNV_offset_basis;
    
    //Iterate through the string
    for(int i=0 ; i<p.size();i++)
    {
        hash = hash * FNV_prime;
        hash = hash ^ p.at(i);
    }
   
    std::cout << hash;  //output 2983
     std::cout << std::hex << hash ; //ba7
}
```

Now I am using it as this

```
int main()
{
   computeHash("Hello");
}
```

I am testing my result [here](http://fnvhash.github.io/fnv-calculator-online/)  and I get the result as **0d47307150c412cf**

**Update:**

I fixed my types to

```
uint8_t            byte_of_data;
uint64_t          hash;
uint64_t          FNV_offset_basis;
uint64_t          FNV_prime;
```

and I get the result fa365282a44c0ba7 which still does not match the result
0d47307150c412cf

Any suggestions on how I can fix this

Comment: Are there not published test vectors against which you can write unit tests?

Comment: a) You need 64bit integers, not 16

Comment: If your hash is of type `uint16_t`, how do you expect to get a 64 bit long result?

Comment: There are options for 32, 64 ... bits. You results comes out when I select 64bit and look at the output of FNV_1. What exactly do you expect to get as output? Mixing the bit length of your data leads to wrong results. :)

Comment: Also, `computeHash` should return the result, not print it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for pointing that out however I would like to get the correct result printed out first before returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current result `fa365282a44c0ba7` is correct according to the official reference
source code (in C) and manual calculation too... this makes the test site wrong.

The reference source files are linked [here](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-reference-source): [C file](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/src/fnv/hash_64.c) and [H file](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/src/fnv/fnv.h)
I removed the includes of `longlong.h` and added following two code parts instead:

```
/*before the reference code*/

#include <stdint.h>
#define HAVE_64BIT_LONG_LONG
typedef uint64_t u_int64_t;
typedef uint32_t u_int32_t;

/*after it*/

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%llx\n", fnv_64_str("Hello", FNV1_64_INIT));
}
```

to make it compile with `gcc -std=c11 source.c`
(`gcc (i686-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.1`)

Output: `fa365282a44c0ba7`.
[And Ideone says so too](http://ideone.com/yypLOx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
uint16_t          FNV_offset_basis;
uint16_t          FNV_prime;
void computeHash(std::string p)
{
    FNV_offset_basis =  0xcbf29ce484222325;
    FNV_prime        =  0x100000001b3;
```

`FNV_prime` and `FNV_offset_basis` are both 16-bit integers in your code, yet inexplicably you're assigning long 64-bit integers to them, your C++ compiler should be warning you about an improper literal assignment.

What happens if your change the types to `uint64_t`?

Comment: And the hash variable too, not just the two vars shown here.

Comment: Yeah, it all needs to be 64bit if 64bit is intended to be used.

Comment: So I change the types to  `uint8_t    byte_of_data;
uint64_t          hash;
uint64_t          FNV_offset_basis;
uint64_t          FNV_prime;`  Now I get the result fa365282a44c0ba7 which is still incorrect